# line collision cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, geometry

I want to do triangular collision detection. So imagine a triangle equilateral for example, whenever an circle goes inside the triangle how do i detect it.
once i manage the detection i would like to have some tiny boxes on the side of the triangle that block the left side a bit. how do i make the lines of the triangle stop at the boxes.i attatched a picture on the comment to my post

```
- (void) draw
{
    for(int i = 0; i < [enemies count]; i++)
    {
        int angle1 = 150;
        int distance1 = 150;
        angle1 = angle1 * M_PI / 180;
        CGPoint start = ((CCSprite *)[enemies objectAtIndex:0]).position;
        CGPoint end = ccp(start.x + distance1 * sin(angle1),
                          start.y + distance1 * cos(angle1));

        ccDrawLine(start, end);
        start = ((CCSprite *)[enemies objectAtIndex:0]).position;
        end = ccp(start.x + distance1 * sin(angle1*-1),
                  start.y + distance1 * cos(angle1*-1));

        ccDrawLine(start, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VAcGr.png

Comment: Would you be willing to use a physics engine, like Box2d or Chipmunk?

Comment: yeah, how would that work